# Select image from folder and preview it with one button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a FileUpload control and a button in a webform to select an image from folder and preview it in a Image Control.But i want to do that processes with one button click without FileUpload Control.
I have added my code snippets below there.Can you help me about that issue?

Thanks in advance.

***Default.aspx***

```html
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPhotoAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Photo" Width="98px" Height="50px" style="background-color:gray;font-weight:bold" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btnPhotoAdd_Click"/> 
        <div style="float:right;margin-right:5px"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="130px" Width="100px" /></div>
```

***Default.aspx.cs***

```
 protected void btnPhotoAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("images/") + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "images/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call button click on file selection using javascript,

Try below code,

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange=" document.getElementById('<%= btnPhotoAdd.ClientID %>').click()"/>
     <asp:Button ID="btnPhotoAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Photo" Width="98px" Height="50px" style="background-color:gray;font-weight:bold" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btnPhotoAdd_Click"/> 
<div style="float:right;margin-right:5px"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="130px" Width="100px" /></div>
```

Comment: I have changed my code according to yours but when  i click on the "btnPhotoAdd" button,i get that error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.PostedFile.get returned null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your user what image they are uploading then using jQuery is the answer. In your case image gets saved and then previewed to the user. Here image is previewed first so that if user wants to change it before hitting upload button he can do that. Please note that i have set `"ClientIdMode"` to `Static` so that asp.net doesn't change the id and jQuery can identify the file upload control by its id.

```
$(function () {
    $("#fileupload").change(function () {
        $("#dvPreview").html("");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
        if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
            if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                $("#dvPreview").show();
                $("#dvPreview")[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
            }
            else {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    $("#dvPreview").show();
                    $("#dvPreview").append("<img />");
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $("#dvPreview img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
        }
    });
});
```

Your aspx page should be something like this.

```
<asp:fileupload runat="server" id="fileupload" ClientIdMode="static" />
<hr />
<b>Preview</b>
<br />
<br />
<div id="dvPreview">
</div>
```